# R code asking Excel to open a file

Tags: r, excel

Here is a real world setting:

1. We download *.xls or *.xlsx files from the web.
2. We open the *.xls or *.xlsx files by double-clicking the files one by one (assuming Excel is installed) in order to eye-ball the file content.

This could become tedious (relatively speaking) if a lot of excel files were downloaded regularly, filed into different directories and need to check the file content one by one.

For example, we downloaded a file as below:

```
url <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FDATA.gov_NGAP.xlsx"
file01 <- file.path(getwd(), "NGAP.xlsx")
download.file(url, file01, mode = "wb")
```

What is the R code to instruct Excel to open this file?  Of course we could go to download directory and double-click the file to open it. But want to instruct Excel to open the file by running R code.  Thanks for any pointers provided!

Comment: That is going to depend on your operating system, look at `system`. But since you are in R anyway why not just check them in R using the xlsx package? Reading them all in as a list of data.frames sounds easier to me.

Comment: Something like `system("open NGAP.xlsx 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\EXCEL.EXE'")` might work (not tested).

Comment: @JeremyS: Very often the data in excel file is messy (not clean) and embedded with lots of graphs, macros etc let alone there could be several worksheets in a workbook.  Thus it's quite common to open the file for a peek so as to decide how to clean the data.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: Thanks. Replaced "\" with "/". It works after running: system("open NGAP.xlsx 'c:/Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office12/EXCEL.exe'"). I'm running Windows7.

Comment: Use `file.show(file01)`.

Comment: @jbaums, yes--that makes much more sense :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `base` function `file.show` opens files with the default application registered to handle the given file extension.

```
u <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FDATA.gov_NGAP.xlsx"
download.file(u, f <- tempfile(fileext='.xlsx'), mode = "wb")
file.show(f)
```